# Google Maps API: Making Variables out of Total Markers

Tags: html, api, google-maps, counter

Sorry if this had already been answered before. I was warned when doing the title that there may be a similar question, but I didn't find anything. I'm doing a statistics based program based off of location data, but I can't figure out how to actually use the results generated as variables. The following code is the base for what I'm working on and provides up to 60 nearby restaurants based on latitude & longitude. Is there any way to take the total number of markers generated, and turn it into a variable that could be referenced in something else, like, for example an HTML table, or some other comparable item that would reference a variable? Also, the API provided should work, but you may need your own API key for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Place search pagination</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 60%;
        margin-top: -195px;
        height: 330px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background: #fff;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 271px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      li {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
      }
      #more {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var map;

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var pyrmont = {lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 17
        });

        // Create the places service.
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        var getNextPage = null;
        var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
        moreButton.onclick = function() {
          moreButton.disabled = true;
          if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
        };

        // Perform a nearby search.
        service.nearbySearch(
            {location: pyrmont, radius: 500, type: ['restaurants']},
            function(results, status, pagination) {
              if (status !== 'OK') return;

              createMarkers(results);
              moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
              getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
                pagination.nextPage();
              };
            });
      }

      function createMarkers(places) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
          var image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,

            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });

          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.textContent = place.name;
          placesList.appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById('number_results').innerHTML = placesList.children.length + " returned";

          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="right-panel">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <div id="number_results"></div>
      <ul id="places"></ul>
      <button id="more">More results</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYoCkx3owRBY3uLwBvW36B0GNeMQtBm1o&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var map;

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var pyrmont = {
    lat: -33.866,
    lng: 151.196
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 17
  });

  // Create the places service.
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var getNextPage = null;
  var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
  moreButton.onclick = function() {
    moreButton.disabled = true;
    if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
  };

  // Perform a nearby search.
  service.nearbySearch({
      location: pyrmont,
      radius: 500,
      type: ['restaurants']
    },
    function(results, status, pagination) {
      if (status !== 'OK') return;

      createMarkers(results);
      moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
      getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
        pagination.nextPage();
      };
    });
}

function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,

      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = place.name;
    placesList.appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById('number_results').innerHTML = placesList.children.length + " returned";

    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 60%;
  margin-top: -195px;
  height: 330px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 271px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

#more {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div id="number_results"></div>
  <ul id="places"></ul>
  <button id="more">More results</button>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

EDIT: To make this a bit more simple to answer, I added a more complete version of the html I'm working on below. (It has a few problems such as the map not updating it's markers, but that's a separate issue entirely). I added a table at the bottom of this code, that has the following phrase
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Based on your latitude of "+lat+" and longitude of "+lng+", the total number of libraries are: "+SomethingSomethingSomething+".";
But I don't know how to get a variable to reference from the results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Base Mapper V2</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #fff
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 60%;
  margin-top: -395px;
  height: 650px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 580px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  background-color: #ffc965;
  padding: 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff065;
}

#more {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ffefe5
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff
  padding: 80px;
  width: 80%
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8f20b6;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #cba00d;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8f20b6;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <form id="mapCenterForm" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="latitude">lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude" placeholder="0.000000">

    <label for="longitude">lng</label>
    <input type="text" id="lng" name="longitude" placeholder="0.000000">
    <br>
    <button onclick="change_center(); return false">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
  <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>

</div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div id="number_results"></div>
  <ul id="places"></ul>
  <button id="more">More Results</button>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBYoCkx3owRBY3uLwBvW36B0GNeMQtBm1o&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">


var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
var map;
var lat = 41.18076;
var lng = -73.20537;

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var SET = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: SET,
    zoom: 13
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latLng.lng();
  })

  // Create the places service.
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var getNextPage = null;
  var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
  moreButton.onclick = function() {
    moreButton.disabled = true;
    if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
  };

  // Perform a nearby search.
  service.nearbySearch({
      location: SET,
      radius: 9500,
      keyword: "library"
    },

    function(results, status, pagination) {
      if (status !== 'OK') return;

      createMarkers(results);
      moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
      getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
        pagination.nextPage();
      };
    });
}

function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: red_icon,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = place.name;
    placesList.appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById('number_results').innerHTML = placesList.children.length+" returned";
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    var spookRating1= li*100
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function change_center() {
  var newLat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
  var newLng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lng").value);

  map.setCenter({
    lat: newLat,
    lng: newLng
  });
  return false;
}

  </script>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "r96szuhx"
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>
  <table>
  <tr><th id="val"></th></tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" font=24>
  document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Based on your latitude of "+lat+" and longitude of "+lng+", the total number of libraries are: "+results.length+".";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would be inclined to see if `results.length` returns the number of results.

Comment: To test this out, I made a line 
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Lat: "+lat+" Lng: "+lng+" Total: "+results.length+".";
but results.length is undefined. "li" and "placesList.children.length" yield a similar error, and "number_results" yields [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Are you sure that you checked for results.length after the results were returned by Google?

Comment: Where do you (or where do you want to) use the number of results?  If they have been returned `document.getElementById('places').children.length` should contain that value (`placesList` is `document.getElementById('places')`).

Comment: To Mike Poole, I believe I added results.length to double check, but that did not work on my end. I might have done something wrong on my end with the way that it's set up however, so that could very well be right. To geocodezip, I'm just going to use the variable in a simple message result at the bottom of the screen to prove that the results are a variable that can be referenced. For the sake of making the question more clear, I edited the question, to provide more code, that is more or less what I'm working with.

Comment: The table at the bottom of the map does provide text depending on the variable entered into it, but (at least on my end) it appears blank when using results.length.

Comment: Why would you want to show the number of results since anyway it won't be *the total number of ...* as you mentioned but a maximum of 60 results. Check `results.length` if it is less than 20, you can show the total number. Otherwise show *20+* or something like that and use pagination... Or just don't show any number.

Comment: MrUpsidown, I need the variables for a future statistics based program. And I can't do it with numbers like "20+". Besides, the radius I'm going to be using is relatively small, and I doubt there's any place in the world that's going to have more than 60 libraries or restaurants or whatever within a small radius. Lastly, I already did try to use results.length as a variable. You can see it in the extended code, but that is not being treated as a variable and gets the error "results is not defined". Now maybe I just did something wrong when typing it, but if I knew what, there'd be no question.

Comment: Yes you did it wrong. `results` is only available from within your `function(results, status, pagination)` function scope. That is the basics of [Javascript variables scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). So you should declare a variable in the global scope, assign it the value of `results.length` in the function I mentioned, and use it where you need it, **or** alter the HTML (`document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = ...`) from within the nearby search callback function (the same one I mentioned, again) where you have access to the `results` variable.

Comment: *I doubt there's any place in the world that's going to have more than 60 libraries or restaurants or whatever within a small radius* - I guess this really depends on what you search for, where, and what you define as a *small radius*... But your code and use-case should *probably* take this case into account... IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the information MrUpsidown. I'll take that into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('places').children.length` will contain the number of results displayed (a maximum of 20 for the first request, up a maximum of 60 with 3 requests).

This will update your table:

```
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Based on your latitude of " + lat + " and longitude of " + lng + ", the total number of libraries are: " + document.getElementById('places').children.length + ".";
```

But you need to call it when the response comes back (in the `createMarkers` function works):

```
function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: red_icon,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = place.name;
    placesList.appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById('number_results').innerHTML = placesList.children.length + " returned";
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    var spookRating1 = li * 100
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Based on your latitude of " + lat + " and longitude of " + lng + ", the total number of libraries are: " + document.getElementById('places').children.length + ".";
}
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map (after clicking "more results" once)]

**code snippet:**

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #fff
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 60%;
  margin-top: -395px;
  height: 650px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 580px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  background-color: #ffc965;
  padding: 5px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff065;
}

#more {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ffefe5
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff padding: 80px;
  width: 80%
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8f20b6;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #cba00d;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8f20b6;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="mapCenterForm" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="latitude">lat</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" name="latitude" placeholder="0.000000">

    <label for="longitude">lng</label>
    <input type="text" id="lng" name="longitude" placeholder="0.000000">
    <br>
    <button onclick="change_center(); return false">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
  <div id="map" style="height: 500px"></div>

</div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <h2>Locations</h2>
  <div id="number_results"></div>
  <ul id="places"></ul>
  <button id="more">More Results</button>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var red_icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
  var map;
  var lat = 41.18076;
  var lng = -73.20537;

  function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
    var SET = {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: SET,
      zoom: 13
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
      document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
      document.getElementById('lng').value = e.latLng.lng();
    })

    // Create the places service.
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    var getNextPage = null;
    var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
    moreButton.onclick = function() {
      moreButton.disabled = true;
      if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
    };

    // Perform a nearby search.
    service.nearbySearch({
        location: SET,
        radius: 9500,
        keyword: "library"
      },

      function(results, status, pagination) {
        if (status !== 'OK') return;

        createMarkers(results);
        moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
        getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
          pagination.nextPage();
        };
      });
  }

  function createMarkers(places) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var placesList = document.getElementById('places');

    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: red_icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = place.name;
      placesList.appendChild(li);
      document.getElementById('number_results').innerHTML = placesList.children.length + " returned";
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      var spookRating1 = li * 100
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "Based on your latitude of " + lat + " and longitude of " + lng + ", the total number of libraries are: " + document.getElementById('places').children.length + ".";
  }

  function change_center() {
    var newLat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
    var newLng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lng").value);

    map.setCenter({
      lat: newLat,
      lng: newLng
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="val"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```